# javascript json hide empty rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-sheets-api

Let's preface this by saying I would consider myself pretty good at manipulating code that already exists to fit my needs, but not strong by any means in writing my own code from scratch.  With that being said, on to the question!

I am using a Google sheet to maintain a large list of statistics for a pool league I am associated with.

Using Javascript/Jquery, I am pulling in the data from the sheet and I am able to format it to my liking for the most part. However, I am running into an issue where, since the code loops through the rows to pull out the items from the sheet and parses to JSON, it is grabbing empty rows for columns that are shorter than the longest column on the sheet.

Here is a sample of how I am grabbing the data and formatting it:

```
// make JSON call to Google Data API
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    // Build the Table Headings for Teams
    var tmname = '';

    tmname += '<table class="table table-sm mb-0 tablesorter stand1">';
    tmname += '<thead>';
    tmname += '<tr>';
    tmname += '<th style="width: 50%;">Team Name</th>';
    tmname += '<th style="width: 50%;" class="text-right">Total Points</th>';
    tmname += '</tr>';
    tmname += '</thead>';
    tmname += '<tbody class="stand1">';

    // Build the Table Rows for Sunday Juniors      

    var sjt8 = '';
    // loop to build html output for 8 Ball Format
    var entrysjt8 = data.feed.entry;
    for (var i = 0; i < entrysjt8.length; i++) {
        sjt8 += '<tr>';
        sjt8 += '<td class="score1">' + entrysjt8[i]['gsx$sjt8name']['$t'] + '</td>';
        sjt8 += '<td class="text-right score1">' + entrysjt8[i]['gsx$sjt8point']['$t'] + '</td>';
        sjt8 += '</tr>';
    }

    var sjtlo = '';
    // loop to build html output for Laggers Option Format
    var entrysjtlo = data.feed.entry;
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < entrysjtlo.length; i1++) {
        sjtlo += '<tr>';
        sjtlo += '<td>' + entrysjtlo[i1]['gsx$sjtloname']['$t'] + '</td>';
        sjtlo += '<td class="text-right">' + entrysjtlo[i1]['gsx$sjtlopoint']['$t'] + '</td>';
        sjtlo += '</tr>';
    }

    // Close the Tables
    var tbclose = '';
    tbclose += '</tbody>';
    tbclose += '</table>';

    // output html - Sunday Juniors     
    $('.sjt8').html(tmname + sjt8 + tbclose);
    $('.sjtlo').html(tmname + sjtlo + tbclose);
});
```

Once the data is grabbed, I am just injecting it to a page with a div call to the defined class.

One workaround I tried to implement was to use a jquery function to hide the empty rows, and tried to get it to fire after the document loaded. That would only work on refresh.  It wouldn't work on the first page load. I then added a timeout of 500ms to the page, and it kinda works. The user sees what happens when it does work, but it seems about 1 in 10 loads the event doesn't fire.  Here is the code for that:

```
console.log('Outside document ready handler ' + $('.test').length)
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('table tbody.stand1 tr').filter(
            function(){
                return $(this).find('td').length == $(this).find('td:empty').length;
                }).hide();
    }, 500);
});
```

I've been trying to find a better solution to this, and I was thinking that if there was a way to check the length of the JSON field, and if null or ="" then append a class which I can then style to hide, or to straight up append style="display: none;".  Thus far, I have not stumbled across anything like that in my searching.

I'm also very open to other ideas.

Here is the page where all the standings get pulled into, if you want to see what I'm using this data for, and how extensive it is:
https://www.westmibcapl.com/leagues/standings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/v7fkj7et/

```js
$('table tr').each(function(){
  var empty = true;
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() != '')
      empty = false;
  });
  
  if(empty)
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Solution explanation**

- Loop through all the `tr` & set a variable with value as `true`
- Then loop through each `td within each tr`
- If any `td contains value` then change the variable value to `false`
- Check for the `variable value with the tr loop` & based on the value hide the `tr` **(if the value is true that means all the td are empty)**

**Alternative solution**

Before appending a row check for value.

```
var sjt8 = '';
// loop to build html output for 8 Ball Format
var entrysjt8 = data.feed.entry;
for (var i = 0; i < entrysjt8.length; i++) {
  if( entrysjt8[i]['gsx$sjt8name']['$t'] != '' && entrysjt8[i]['gsx$sjt8point']['$t'] != '') {
    sjt8 += '<tr>';
    sjt8 += '<td class="score1">' + entrysjt8[i]['gsx$sjt8name']['$t'] + '</td>';
    sjt8 += '<td class="text-right score1">' + entrysjt8[i]['gsx$sjt8point']['$t'] + '</td>';
    sjt8 += '</tr>';
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That is giving me similar results.  I have to run it after the page loads, with a 500ms delay to remove the rows.  I'm looking for a solution to hide them before the page loads, or to not even load the empty rows at all.

Thank you so much for taking the time to help though :)

Comment: @WayneBaker The best solution will be not to append the empty rows. While appending the rows check for empty rows & skip them from appending. **Hide a table before the page load is not possible as much as I know.**

Comment: That's where I'm a little fuzzy.  I don't know how to skip over the empty rows and not append them.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect, and I'm ashamed it was so easy.  I just updated the entire site with the if statements.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @WayneBaker Welcome buddy :)